# Listview show data issue

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, devexpress, itemssource

I have created a "Listview" and a "Gridview" to show some data, and everything looks fine, but whenever I add data to the "Listviews ItemsSource", it doesn't show it, the only thing I can see are marked lines (see below).

The XAML code for the build up is as follows:

```
<ListView Name="lstView">
                <ListView.View>
                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Info">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item}" Header="Item" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Qty}"  Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>Qty
                            <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                                <ContextMenu  
                                    Name="Quantity">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Ascending" />
                                    <MenuItem Header="Descending" />
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Price}" 
                  Header="Price" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

CS part:(forgot to add this part, the class used to store the data)

Class used:

```
public class MaterialsPicked
{
    public string Item;
    public double Qty;
    public double Price;
}
```

And the data inserted:

```
ObservableCollection<MaterialsPicked> materialsPicked = new ObservableCollection<MaterialsPicked>
        {
            new MaterialsPicked { Item = "Test", Qty = 1, Price = 200 },
            new MaterialsPicked { Item = "Test2", Qty = 2, Price = 400 }
        };
        lstView.ItemsSource = materialsPicked;
```

And here is a picture of window, clearly it does add 2 lines to the listview, but the data itself is not showing up, and I am unsure what exactly I am missing.

[image: ListView - GridView - ItemsSource]

Comment: Make sure that Item, Qty and Price are public properties.

Comment: Hey @Clemens

Thanks for the quick response, in my haste I forgot to add the class I use to store data in, as you can see both the class and properties are public, but do you still think its an issue?

Comment: That are fields, not properties.

Comment: @Clemens

Thanks a lot Clemens, instantly fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Clemens

Had the simple solution.

I was using fields instead of properties, changing it to public properties fixed the issue.